# "expected expression before char" inside function

Tags: c, function, expression, call, declaration

I made a function which creates a game board and want to call it on my main. Also, the variable that it uses is a global variable defined outside the main (char board[3][3])

I tried defining char board[3][3] inside main as well but the error keeps appearing, and I don't want to use it as a local variable of the function since I use it in other functions (that i ommited in this portion of code) as well

```
char board[3][3] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

void Tablero(char board[3][3]) {

     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

         for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){

            if(j < 2){
                 printf("   %c   |",board[i][j]);
             }
            else{
                 printf("   %c",board[i][j]);
             }
         }
         if(i < 2){
                 printf("\n-----------------------\n");
         }
     }

  }

int main (){

     Tablero(char board[3][3]);
     return 0;

  }
```

the error that appears is

```
 tictactoe.c: In function 'main':
 tictactoe.c:203:10: error: expected expression before 'char'
 Tablero(char board[3][3]);
```

Comment: The compiler says that `Tablero(char board[3][3]);` is nonsensical, because it is. There's nothing else to say - study functions in your C programming book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This in main

```
Tablero(char board[3][3]);
```

is an incorrect function declaration with an absent return type.

I think you mean the call of the function instead of the declaration

```
Tablero( board );
```